# How to keep a node oriented correctly after rotating in SpriteKit

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit

I'm running into an issue when I try to make a fish swim naturally towards its new point while moving.

I'm using a recursive function to constantly move each fish to a new position on the screen, before it moves it should rotate to the angle at which the new point exists relative to its current point.  All of that works, however, once it rotates sometimes the fish is upside down or backwards.  After some statements I added to flip the Y scale of the fish if the angle is in a specific quadrant, it got better.  But it's still not perfect.  Any ideas how I can always make sure the fish is oriented correctly?

The image asset at 0 degrees is facing left.  Originally I had it facing right as I read that is what SpriteKit's coordinate system is expecting, but that did not produce the expected result at all.

This is all part of a SKSpriteNode extension called `move`, hence the recursive call at the end.

```
let angle = atan2(self.position.y - newPoint.y, self.position.x - newPoint.x)
self.zRotation = angle

if angle > 0 && angle < 1.57 {
   self.yScale = abs(self.yScale)
}else if angle > 1.57 {
   self.yScale = self.yScale.negative()
}else if angle < 0 && angle > -1.57 {
   self.yScale = abs(self.yScale)
}else if angle < -1.57 {
   self.yScale = self.yScale.negative()
}

self.run(SKAction.move(to: newPoint,duration: timeToPoint),completion:{
   self.move(within: frame,withSpeed: timeToPoint,excluding: rect,isFish: isFish)
})
```

Comment: What does `negative()` do?

Comment: Just a CGFloat extension.  `return self = 0 - self` basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the sprite's `yScale` to be positive if the sprite is moving to the right and negative if it's moving to the left. Negating `yScale` doesn't work correctly if you want the sprite to move to the left and it's already facing to the left (i.e., `yScale` is already negative). In this case, `yScale` will be positive. Also, since angles are often difficult to work with, here's another way to solve the problem:

```
let dx = self.position.x - newPoint.x
self.yScale = dx < 0 ? -abs(self.yScale) : abs(self.yScale)
```

or use your existing code and change the extension to

```
extension CGFloat {
    func negative() -> CGFloat {
        return -abs(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: Or you're thinking my `0-self` will make it positive if already negative?  I suppose that's reasonable, let me see. Thanks.

Comment: Yyyyyep, that was it.  I can't believe i didn't catch that double negative possibility.  I would suggest adding this as the reason for your answer. 
 Thank you sir.